# Running virtual machines: Linux vs Windows 7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have tried running windows xp development virtual machine under windows 7 and the performance was dreadful.

I'm considering installing Linux and running the virtual machine from the Linux, but I'm not sure whether I can expect any performance gains?

It's a 2.4ghz core 2 duo machine with 4gb ram and 5400 rpm hdd.

Can somebody please recommend very cut down version of linux that can run VMWare player and isn't resource hungry?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Not really a Stack Overflow question, but it sounds like you might want to look into using [VMware ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/). It doesn't need a host OS to run virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

That may not be a windows issue. Does your CPU support hardware virtualization / have it activated? If not - and intel can be tricky here - performacne WILL be bad on ALL virtualization "emulators". Hardware virtualization support is the key.

Comment: I'll look into proc. specification in a minute. Thanks for that

Comment: Also check bios - hardware support may simple be off there.

Answer (score 1):

I am running xp and ubuntu virtual machines on my win 7 laptop and have no problems at all. I use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) not VM. Just make sure that you allocate enough RAM and Video RAM to the virtual machine

Comment: I'll give virtual box a go if the VMWAre doesnt do the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is almost same spec as yours and windows 7 is installed. I can run Windows XP, Windows 2003, and Linux Vritual machines on it (not at the same time). I am using VMWare and performance is quite acceptable. I am running Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP Virtual machine :).
When I run virtual machine, I close all applications and unnecessary services on physical machine and keep less than 1GB RAM for physical machine.